# Accessing API’s on WSO2 API Manager using JWT Tokens

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to access APIs on WSO2 API manager by using JWT token.

How to Access API’s on WSO2 API Manager using JWT Tokens.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported OOB. WSO2 API Manager supports only Oauth2 tokens. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Working+with+Access+Tokens

Comment: Are you sure? You can use WSO2 API Manager with WSO2 Identity Server which supports JWT.

Comment: You can use a JWT and get an Oauth2 access token. That's is the only option which supports OOB.

Comment: Right, here is the link in case anyone is looking for that: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/JWT+Grant+Type+for+OAuth2